# Agile JIRA Authentication failure

Tags: authentication, jira-rest-api, http-status-code-401, jira-agile

I am trying to get the token for my agile-jira server but getting

> "401 Unauthorized"

for the below url I am using to get it done.

```
https://agile-jira.mycompany.com/jira/rest/auth/1/session
```

I am using             **Authorization** as **Basic Auth**
In header I am setting **content-type** to  **application/json**

Using POSTMAN as my tool for sending REST calls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should provide the **encoded base64 user and password** alongside the basic authentication.

For the `Authorization`, provide `Basic base64(user:password)` parameter.

`base64` is a function that'll depend on how you're running these commands.

If it's from Linux curl, this approach might work: `"Authorization: Basic $(echo -n user:pass | base64)"`

**References:**

https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/basic-authentication/

https://osric.com/chris/accidental-developer/2018/07/curl-basic-auth-base64-encoded-credentials/